# With LightInject, how can I pass arguments to child dependencies without registering a bunch of factories?

Tags: light-inject

In the code below, I am trying to inject a ViewModel into a View, while the ViewModel requires a Model to wrap and another service that is in the container.  The Model is not registered as it is not really a "service".

How do I:

a) not have to provide the IService instance as an argument (let the container resolve it),

b) not have to register a factory for my ViewModels (there will be *many*)

So what I'm really asking the container to do is treat my Model (that I pass as an argument) as if it were a registered "service" for the duration of this call to GetInstance.

If this is not possible with LightInject, are there any containers out there that have something like this?

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var container = new LightInject.ServiceContainer();
        var service = new Service1();
        container.RegisterInstance<IService>(service);

        // Have to register the factory
        container.Register<IService, PersonModel, PersonViewModel>(
                (f, s, p) => new PersonViewModel(s, p));

        container.Register<View>();

        var person = new PersonModel(); // this is contextual -- not a service.
        object view = CreateView(container, typeof(View), service, person);

        // ultimate desired code:
        //var view = container.GetInstance(typeof(View), new object[] { person });

    }

    private static object CreateView(ServiceContainer container, Type viewType, IService service, object model)
    {
        var ctor = viewType.GetConstructors()[0];
        var parameters = new List<object>();
        foreach (var param in ctor.GetParameters())
        {
            var attr = param.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ModelAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
            if (model != null && attr != null)
            {
                parameters.Add(model);
            }
            else
            {
                parameters.Add(container.GetInstance(param.ParameterType, new object[] { service, model }));
            }
        }
        return Activator.CreateInstance(viewType, parameters.ToArray());
    }
}

public interface IService
{
}

public class Service1 : IService
{
}

public class PersonModel
{
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
    public PersonModel PersonModel { get; set; }
    public PersonViewModel(IService service, [Model] PersonModel person)
    {
        PersonModel = person;
    }
}

public class View
{
    public PersonViewModel PersonViewModel { get; set; }
    public View(PersonViewModel vm)
    {
        PersonViewModel = vm;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class ModelAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

Comment: I have partially answered part a) in that a factory gets an IServiceFactory, which you can resolve the service from, but I'd still like to not register a bunch of factories.            container.Register<PersonModel, PersonViewModel>(
                    (f, p) => new PersonViewModel(f.GetInstance<IService>(), p));

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issues with a combination of techniques...

a) use a Scope and register the ViewModel and View with PerScopeLifetime.

b) use a "ModelTracker" registered with a factory to allow an instance not created by the container to be injected (since models will be created by client code or a DbContext).

This combination also allows me to not register a factory for every ViewModel type -- but instead use the built-in mass registration functions (like RegisterAssembly).

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var container = new LightInject.ServiceContainer();

        container.RegisterInstance<IService>(new Service1());

        container.Register<View>(new PerScopeLifetime());
        container.Register<PersonViewModel>(new PerScopeLifetime());
        container.Register<ModelTracker>(new PerScopeLifetime());
        container.Register<PersonModel>((f) => (PersonModel)f.GetInstance<ModelTracker>().Instance);

        using (var scope = container.BeginScope())
        {
            var tracker = scope.GetInstance<ModelTracker>();
            tracker.Instance = new PersonModel() { Name = "person1" };

            var view = scope.GetInstance<View>();
        }

    }

}

public class ModelTracker
{
    public object Instance { get; set; }
}

public class PersonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class PersonViewModel
{
    private readonly IService service;
    private readonly PersonModel person;

    public PersonViewModel(IService service, PersonModel person)
    {
        this.service = service;
        this.person = person;
    }
}

public class View
{
    public PersonViewModel PersonViewModel { get; set; }
    public View(PersonViewModel vm)
    {
        PersonViewModel = vm;
    }
}

public interface IService { }
public class Service1 : IService { }
```